# Data recovery from deleted NTFS partition

Tags: data-recovery

I need some advice on the steps/approach to data restore in following scenario: NTFS partition was deleted using Windows Disk Management by accident (OS in case somebody needs such detail is Windows 10 TP), then new partition was create and deleted. No disk format was performed or data written to disk afterwards since then. What type of utilities should I employ in attempt to recover some of my data? I tried couple of partition recovery utilities with no luck so far.

Comment: TestDisk is very effective for partitions that were deleted, but not overwritten or otherwise damaged. With any tool, you are best advised to restore to a different device, so you don't overwrite the very data you are trying to recover. The new partition may have overwritten parts of the old, so you will have to see what TestDisk detects. failing that, look into tools like Photorec and easus for recovering files if the partition cannot be recovered.

Comment: in terms of Open Source recovery software, this guide is particularly useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your budget and what hardware you have access to.

There are professional computer forensic service that will happily retrieve your data for a reasonable cost. I've had hdd with broken controller, crashed head etc. done by them before, costs about £500-£1000. So your scenario is just a walk in the park for them.

For DIY recovery, I've had good experience and many success with "GetDataBack NTFS" in the past. It does require some knowledge about computers and hard disks in general, but if you don't have those knowledge, you really shouldn't be doing it.

If you only know how to use Windows, then you will have to find a working box, install the recovery software, change the settings for disk discovery etc. (Windows by default will mount the new hdd like flash drives, try to scan it, reformat it if it doesn't understand what's going on.), the last thing you want is to write to the hdd. GetDataBack is pretty safe to use, it doesn't try to do anything too clever, it's Windows you have to watch out for.

Linux is more honest with these things. I usually use ddrescue to make a binary copy of the hdd first, then mount it as ready-only for a Windows VM, and run GetDataBack from there.

The general idea is to make a read only binary copy of the hdd first, for maximum safety, then do the recovery from there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to GetDataBack NTFS - will try this (it seems I tried it long time ago on similar occasion). I have at least 2 working boxes at my disposal and a bit of knowledge about computers, though mainly in Windows/Microsoft domain :)

Comment: If a new partition is created, then you wiped out the FAT backup.  Whatever recovery option left it will be sector by sector recovery which would be expensive and time consuming.

Comment: @user2539817 Marked your response as an answer as I'm successfully restored all my data GetDataBack NTFS :) And it was quick especially by contrast with couple of other partition recovery utilities which scanned drive for hours but was not able to restore anything...

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!